# Convention for separating layout styling from graphic styling?

Tags: html, css, layout, graphics

I had cases where I had to change a layout and it was hard to distinguish the layout args from the graphic args. For example, `fonts, colors, borders, decorations`, etc. are related to graphics where as `display, position, float`, etc. are related to layout.

Also, separation can lead to better reuse. Some views might need to reuse only the graphics where as other views might need to reuse only the layout.

So...**is there a convention for modeling differently the layout from the graphics in web development styling**? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to apply the layout rules to other elements seperately from the decorative rules, you can simply write two CSS classes, one for decorative rules, the other for layout rules, then use the classes seperately.

Comment: Which is what Bootstrap basically does,,,no?

Comment: @Paulie_D I don’t have much experience with Bootstrap, but my guess is, that the CSS classes in Bootstrap are like “templates” for the most common sets of CSS rules, that you can combine as you like.

Comment: Yep, it has a set of 'Scaffolding' classes for general layout and then presentational 'helper' classes for everythnig else. Ditto for the  "Foundation" framework and, I'm sure, others.